# ¿Cómo guardar un campo json en la base de datos mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Estoy probando de insertar varios campos en formato json en una tabla mysql , pero no soy capaz de guardarlos.

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 JSONArray arrObj = jsonObject.getJSONArray("postalCodes");
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        for(int i=0;i<arrObj.length();i++){
            PostalCodeDTO postalCodeDTO = new PostalCodeDTO();
            JSONObject ob= arrObj.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(ob);
            if (ob.has("adminName1") && !ob.isNull("adminName1")) {
                postalCodeDTO.setAdminName1(gson.toJson(ob.getString("adminName1")));
            }
}
```

El modelo de la base de datos

```
@Entity
public class PostalCodeDTO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "postalCode_id")
    private Integer postalCodeId;

    private String adminCode3;
    private String adminCode2;
    private String adminCode1;
    private JSON adminName1;
    private String adminName2;

}
```

Esto recupera el adminName1 de la API de Geonames , cómo podría hacer para guardar un JSON correctamente en mysql ?

Saludos !

Answer (score 1):

**Aclaración el dato de tipo JSON solo esta disponible desde la versión MySQL 5.7 en adelante**

Depende que versión de MySQL  estás usando; por ejemplo si es MySQL 5.7 y ya tienes creadas tus tablas puedes ejecutar el comando siguiente para añadir una columna de tipo JSON

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN data_history JSON NOT NULL;
```

Si por el contrario vas a hacer tus tablas desde cero puedes construirla de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    attributes JSON NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Para poder insertar un nuevo valor te dejo este ejemplo

Primero dentro de una variable por fines de rapidez declaro una estructura así

```
 CREATE TABLE facts (sentence JSON);
```

Posteriormente si quiero guardar un nuevo elemento a esa estructura lo hago así

Por medio de la función JSON_OBJECT

```
INSERT INTO facts VALUES
        (JSON_OBJECT("mascot", "Our mascot is a dolphin named \"Sakila\"."));
```

O directamente así

```
INSERT INTO facts VALUES
        ('{"mascot": "Our mascot is a dolphin named \\"Sakila\\"."}');
```

Fuente:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices perfectamente , pero creo que tengo una versión erronea de MySQL ya que con el comando Select @@version me dice que tengo la versión 10.1.28-MariaDB , de todas formas como lo hago en el modelo es correcto ?

Comment: tampoco te va a funcionar el JSON estas usando MariaDB pero en dicho software JSON es soportado únicamente desde la versión 10.2 por lo tanto tampoco podrás así @perobuenoestoquees

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas , toca actualizar el software pues suerte que no he empezado antes jajjaja